# JSON Encoding Error in PHP Array when executing pg_query in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-maps

I have an address returned from a pg_query that I have converted to latitude and longitude values. I then have javascript that utilizes those values to place map markers over google maps. I am getting the following error:

```
VM884:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 35
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (map.php:37)
```

The JSON encoded data is:

```
[{"lat":43.66852,"lng":-70.245084}][{"lat":43.66852,"lng":-70.245084}]
```

Here is the PHP:

```
$arr = array();
while ($markers = pg_fetch_row($address)){
$request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$markers[0]."&sensor=true";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
$status = $xml->status;
if ($status=="OK") {
$arr = array();
$Lat = (float)$xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
$Lng = (float)$xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
$arr[] = array("lat" => $Lat, "lng" => $Lng);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Here is the JS:

```
  function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: {lat: 39.350033, lng: -94.6500523}
    });

    // Do not actually need labels for our purposes, but the site_id is best if they are required.
    var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';



    // Add some markers to the map.
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
console.log(xhr.responseText);
if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    if(Array.isArray(arr)){
        showMarkers(arr);
    }
}
}
xhr.open('GET', 'markers.php', true);
xhr.send();

function showMarkers(locations){
var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    label: labels[i % labels.length]
  });
});

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png'});
}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json response need to be like this

```
[{"lat":43.66852,"lng":-70.245084},{"lat":43.66852,"lng":-70.245084}]
```

and the php

```
$arr = array();
while ($markers = pg_fetch_row($address)){
    $request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$markers[0]."&sensor=true";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
    $status = $xml->status;
    if ($status=="OK") {
        $Lat = (float)$xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
        $Lng = (float)$xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
        $arr[] = array("lat" => $Lat, "lng" => $Lng);
    }
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Right, How do I get that result?

Comment: $arr = array();
while ($markers = pg_fetch_row($address)){
...
}
echo json_encode($arr);
Note the end of the while

Comment: Thanks for the info... Moving the echo outside of the loop results in it only showing the first record.

Comment: I put the fixe on the answer, you crushed the array in your loop

Comment: Excellent, Thank you